# Rails - How do you access nested params attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have

```
item_params = {
  "name" => "",
  "description" => "",
  "tag_list" => "",
  "user_items_attributes" => {"0" => {"user_id" => "8"}},
  "created_by" => 8,
  "status" => 0
}
```

and I want to access the user_id to change it.

I tried `params[:item][:user_items_attributes][0]` and it doesn't work.  I also tried `params[:item][:user_items_attributes][0][:user_id]`.  What is the correct way to change the `user_id`?

Comment: This one is tricky, try using 0 as a string: `params[:item][:user_items_attributes]['0']`. The reason your code does not work is that calling `{}[<Integer>]` will try to change your hash to an array and access its first element, or try to change your hash to a string a access to the first letter (ex: `'hello'[0]` returns `'h'`)

Comment: What is `params`? Where does `:item` come from?

Comment: which ruby version you are using ?? the given answer is relevant only if the version ruby 2.3.0

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The value of `params[:item][:user_items_attributes]` is a hash mapping a string to a hash. You're trying to access it using an integer `0` instead of `'0'`:

```
params[:item][:user_items_attributes]['0']
 => {"user_id"=>"8"}
```

You can often access hashes using symbol keys rather than the string keys that will display if you inspect the hash because of rails' [HashWithIndifferentAccess](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html) but you'll need to use a string for the key in this case.

Answer (score 7):

Starting from Ruby 2.3.0 you can use `Hash#dig` method which is safer than accessing with `Hash#[]`. You can find some useful examples [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0_preview1/Hash.html#method-i-dig).

In your case it will look like:

```
user_id = item_params.dig("user_items_attributes", "0", "user_id")
```

Answer (score 3):

That's quite easy to solve!

```
params["user_items_attributes"] #=> {"0" => {"user_id" => "8" }}
```

So if you want to just get the user_id:

```
params["user_items_attributes"]["0"]["user_id"] #=> "8"
```

Answer (score 0):

the best way to access the user_id is

```
2.2.1 :122 >   item_params = {
2.2.1 :123 >       "name" => "",
2.2.1 :124 >       "description" => "",
2.2.1 :125 >       "tag_list" => "",
2.2.1 :126 >       "user_items_attributes" => {"0" => {"user_id" => "8"}},
2.2.1 :127 >       "created_by" => 8,
2.2.1 :128 >       "status" => 0
2.2.1 :129?>   }
 => {"name"=>"", "description"=>"", "tag_list"=>"", "user_items_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"user_id"=>"8"}}, "created_by"=>8, "status"=>0} 
2.2.1 :130 > item_params['user_items_attributes']['0']['user_id']
 => "8"
```